# When is a PHP-FPM child relseased with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a page that has lots of images and therefore requests. The images are provided by users, so I am using php readfile and each request uses a php child.

So my question is at what point is a child freed? Is it once the file is received at the client, or once the file is pushed to nginx? How does a PHP-FPM lifecycle work?

Comment: A child is ready to process a new request after it serves the one it's working on. That's the cycle, it gets one, does work, sends it back and at that point it's ready for a new task. Nginx doesn't have anything to do with that, it can timeout if it is waiting for a request to be answered for too long (usually 30 seconds, you can modify that).

Comment: So after a php script reads a picture, is that child still tied up until the last bit is recieved by the client, or as soon as it pushed the last bit to nginx is the child free. Say with readfile there is a 100mb file. And the client is on a 56k modem what becomes the limiting factor?

Comment: Limiting factor becomes the connection between nginx and the user, not between how fast the file will be read and then sent back to nginx. The child won't be affected by the lack of speed on the user's side.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.